# Extract hidden text from bmp image

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = open("ship.bmp", 'rb')
data =f.read()[14:]
f.close()
mask=0b00000011

for byte in data:
    new_byte=mask&byte
```

This is my code so far. I am trying to extract the hidden text from the ship.bmp. I have made a byte array until know as you can see and now i want to extract the last 2 bits from each byte and reassemble the two bits fragments into bytes of the hidden text and output it. I tried to this by masking the bytes but i guess i was doing it wrong. If someone could help me it would be really appreciated. I posted many questions in here sorry about that but i really want to get done with this.

Comment: Please be more specific how hidden text is encoded. I gather it's in the lower bits of each byte from your code, but even that is imprecise -- is the image color or grayscale, how many bits per color, how many bits per character of text, etc

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the hidden bit pairs are encoded into the image data from high to low, i.e. `0b11100100` has `11` in the 1st byte, `10` in the 2nd, `01` in the 3rd byte, `00` in the 4th byte. Etc.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python    

def packbits(t):
    return (t[0]<<6) | (t[1]<<4) | (t[2]<<2) | t[3]

def decrypt(data):
    bits = [c&3 for c in bytearray(data)]
    blocks = zip(*[iter(bits)] * 4)
    return str(bytearray([packbits(u) for u in blocks]))

data = 'Qlnd!rameno uf{t!bcwhng `r `!sugebooes`rijc abqd'
print `decrypt(data)`
```

**output**

```
'Hello, world'
```

Tested on Python 2.6.6

I'm happy to show you the code, but I won't explain how it works: I'm not comfortable explaining steganographic algorithms in public... and please don't ask to see the encryption function.